# Transaction status true when sent to an address which doesn't have anything

Tags: solidity, transactions, receipts, besu

When you create a transaction calling a function in a smart contract the transaction status is true if it's executed correctly and false if it isn't

When testing in Hyperledger Besu, if a transaction calling a function in a smart contract which doesn't exists (IE: properly encoded tx to a wrong address), the transaction shows as successfully executed.

For example:
I successfully deploy a smart contract, I create the smart contract instance with the ABI + address, and make a call to the smart contract like so:

```
myContract.methods.myMethod(123).call({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'}, function(error, result){
    ...
});
```

When I recover the transaction receipt I can verify that the transaction status is true.

But if I send the same transaction to an address where there is nothing deployed, I don't get any logs the function may have, which makes sense because there is nothing deployed there. but I also get transaction status true:

```
result:  {
  transactionReceipt: {
    blockHash: '0xea2a7a30fcba0359b76d93d1fe4bc9c97216a720d30022b53eb9111fada263ef',
    blockNumber: 22,
    contractAddress: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 30424,
    from: '0x90f8bf6a479f320ead074411a4b0e7944ea8c9c1',
    gasUsed: 30424,
    logs: [],
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Any idea why that happens? Why wouldn't the transaction get rejected?

Comment: Can you reproduce the behaviour in a different client?

Comment: Yes, it happens in all clients

Comment: Seems like it's default protocol behavior and something we have to code around (IE you can't just call a function from another smart contract and assume true or 0 without checking that the contract you expect is deployed there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a perfectly valid use to use a transaction data field to store messages.

And it is cheaper than using a contract if your data is read only.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, would there be any difference if the transaction got rejected thou?
IE: You sent a transaction the destination can't interpret because there is no code that there that can process it so it rejects it and still introduce it into the block
Your message would still be stored

Comment: @EnriqueAlcazar It might work but it doesn't make much sense to flag a transaction as failed when it didn't fail. Now, it is too late to change its behavior.